# How to covert phantom wallet secretKey to Uint8Array length 64

Tags: phantom

I want to encode my secretKey to Uint8Array.

I use TextEncoder().

```
const secret = new TextEncoder().encode(secretKey);
```

I get secretKey from my phantom wallet.

it returns Uint8Array which is length 88. I need to Uint8Array which is length 64.

I want to convert it to Uint8Array which has 64 length.

Comment: I figure out ! I use bs58 library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the script I use for this:

```
import pkg from 'bs58';
const { decode } = pkg;

const args = process.argv.slice(2);
if (!args.length) {
  throw new Error('No key provided')
}

const key = args[0];
const decoded = decode(key)

console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(decoded)))
```

You can call it with eg. `node decode.js 5Ab... > key.json` where `5aB...` is your base-58 encoded private key from eg. Phantom

And then it'll save in `key.json` the 64-length Uint8array in the format the Solana CLI expects, ie a JSON array.

Answer (score 1):

```
let bs58 = require("bs58");
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");
  const bs = bs58.decode(secretKey);

  const wallet = Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs);
```

I can call it with base58 library !