# Can someone give a real world example of how a Solana transaction would look like?

Tags: cli, send-transaction

I see the following documentation on: https://docs.solana.com/cli/transfer-tokens#send-tokens

```
solana transfer --from <KEYPAIR> <RECIPIENT_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS> <AMOUNT> --fee-payer <KEYPAIR>
```

But can someone give me a real life example of how this output should be with real addresses and keypairs?

I'm a bit confused with KEYPAIR, is this a file or the private key? Can I just pass in a base58 private key? What if I only have the 24 word seed of a wallet? Can I pass in the seed into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `KEYPAIR` is a file containing a Solana keypair, it'll be a JSON file containing an array of 64 bytes (numbers 0-255).

You generate it using `solana-keygen new`. That'll create it at `~/.config/solana/id.json`

Here's a complete example, transferring from a keypair I've created at temp.json to the public key `3GWzdwDqphjz5zi4s8fpeNi5YXKqFSgcMq86BRnS3dnS`:

```
$ solana transfer --from ~/.config/solana/temp.json 3GWzdwDqphjz5zi4s8fpeNi5YXKqFSgcMq86BRnS3dnS 0.1 --allow-unfunded-recipient --fee-payer ~/.config/solana/temp.json

Signature: 5UDry1YScxWRtcjCHxnyGcRxS2DxHxhFnmnHYMr77TVrJWieHZmCy25pvpMfH39xLBQbnjMsXqDJZKfaptQWv7VS

$ solana balance 3GWzdwDqphjz5zi4s8fpeNi5YXKqFSgcMq86BRnS3dnS
0.1 SOL
```

Comment: but what if i only have the base58 private key string? How do I send with that? Also what do you do with the signature?

Comment: You can write a small script that takes the private key and outputs the keypair file, see my answer here: https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/1044/289. Then you can use whichever file you output that to where I have `~/.config/solana/temp.json` (as `KEYPAIR`). The signature just identifies the transaction and lets you view it in future, you can see my one for this answer on explorer here: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/5UDry1YScxWRtcjCHxnyGcRxS2DxHxhFnmnHYMr77TVrJWieHZmCy25pvpMfH39xLBQbnjMsXqDJZKfaptQWv7VS?cluster=devnet

Comment: is there a way to just skip the creation of the keypair .json file and just use the base58 string instead? I have all the private keys stored in a database, and that means every time I  make a transaction this script will be creating a .json file to just make a send transaction?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of if you want to use the CLI, but take that with a grain of salt because I'm not an expert there. In your case though I'd just write a NodeJS script because there you can create a `Keypair` object in `@solana/web3.js` directly from the base58 key and then use that to sign transactions. Plus if you're reading from a DB that's probably going to make much more sense in a NodeJS script than something in the CLI too. See the TS code example here: https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-send-sol